# Spring needs defining a bean, but bean is exists

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring-boot application with mongodb. I'm trying to add paging search capability. But a error happens:

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.life.library.adapter.port.out.mongo.MongoPortImpl required a bean of type 'com.life.library.adapter.port.out.mongo.repository.BookRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.life.library.adapter.port.out.mongo.repository.BookRepository' in your configuration.
```

My repositories:

```java
public interface BookSearchRepository {
  Page<BookDocument> search();
}

@Repository
public interface BookRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<BookDocument, String>, BookSearchRepository {
}
```

Implementation of `BookSearchRepository` repository:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookSearchRepositoryImpl implements BookSearchRepository {

  private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @Override
  public Page<BookDocument> search(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Class, where I am trying to make autowaring of `BookRepository`:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MongoPortImpl implements CreatePort, GetPort, SavePort {

  private final BookRepository bookRepository;
}
```

Comment: please include package names for each and your spring application class